# How can I implement an in-app affiliate program?

Tags: in-app-purchase, affiliate, promotions

My company has an app that connects vendors and clients; searching, booking, and payments done exclusively through the app. We do not currently have an option for booking through a website, just the app. We would like to create an affiliate program that provides a unique code to each affiliate that gives a discount to users (at check out for their booked service). Is this possible? Thanks!